# AndroidStudio не работает(Windows)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Доброго времени суток!Я установил андроид студио и ява,но установить сдк не получается точнее интегрировать его в андроид сдк.Я нажимаю установить,он скачался но как его сделать рабочим не знаю.что нужно сделать для того чтобы зароботал андроид студио помогите пожалуйста

Comment: может путь к сдк надо указать в настройках?

Comment: видимо здесь *File -> Settings -> Appearance&Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK: Android SDK Location (Edit)* нужно указать путь до него теперь. [скриншот](https://developer.android.com/studio/images/sdk-manager-tools_2x.png)